# How can I make the two parameters of a function match an union of defined interfaces?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I tried to limit the two parameters to the attributes "a" and "b" of the interface. In the example, you can see that we restricted them to have the same type (string or number). Since {a: 1, b: '1'} does not match, calling x (1, '1') is expected to be wrong.
It’s actually more complicated to type A, so I don’t want to manually split a and b.
Do you know what should I do?

```js
type A = {
    a: string; // complex type
    b: string; // complex type
} | {
    a: number; // complex type
    b: number; // complex type
}
// | ... | ... | ... and more

function x<T extends A, X extends T['a'], Y extends T['b']>(a: X, b: Y) {

}

x(1, '1') // make this invalid, because { a: number; b: string } does not extends A
```

Playground Link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=84#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNxQD0NUAxgPYC2YANhAB5SiRoYARrgIkK1Oo1YduvcBBQBfKAB9kA9DiikAri0ERCE+szacefBRijDteg0donp5uf0UpJagHS-VUX29-QKxSABMoFiZCBRQAMx1SBmBiJlIoLgAeABUobmAIcLxYABooAA08rgKiqGyAbQByTEaAXTKATSqasOKGxsE2gD4ACi1ystsOgEp1JRQULhGARjLG5cbZyRZMAGtoYAALYmKyADdMdmIwyYgGTB08aCQsXF19Q2pbUTJyKGUwkwIMVSExgN1Cr1YEA

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
type TS = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
} | {
    a: number;
    b: number;
} | {
    a: number,
    b: boolean
}

type Assignable<T, U> = U extends any ? T extends U ? U : never : never

function x<
    A extends TS['a'],
    S extends Assignable<A, TS['a']>,
    B extends Extract<TS, { a: S }>['b']>(a: A, b: B) {
}

x(1, '1')
// Argument of type '"1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | boolean'
```

Comment: I've renamed some stuff, but it does its job :D

Comment: You may want to look at discriminated union types for this. Note you can also use a string enum instead of magic strings for the keys! Check out this guide I googled for you: https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/understanding-discriminated-unions-in-typescript-1ccc0e053cf5